# How to replicate content from one site collection to another site collection?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

On office 365 we created one site collection name "https://abc.sharepoint.com/teams/testsite" where we have all our development, now we want to move our content from testsite to abc.sharepoint.

Please let me know if there are any ways to do his.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have two options:

1. To use a third party tool like [ShareGate](http://en.share-gate.com/) for this. I have used it and it works great.
2. Use [Provisioning Framework](https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP/tree/master/Scenarios/Provisioning.Framework.Console) by PnP.

P.S. If you have a publishing site, then you are left with option 1 for now.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried saving your source site collection as Template ?

Try saving it as Site-Template by adding the site in your network locations as described in [This Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_cloud/archive/2012/03/11/migrating-content-between-sharepoint-online-site-collections.aspx). Let me know if it was useful to you.

Thanks.

Edit for Publishing Issue :

Try enabling the "SaveSiteAsTemplateEnabled" to True from SPD.

Follow [This](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/05/03/missing-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites-in-sharepoint-2013/).

This entry shows for the SharePoint on-prem, but I think it might work in SP-online as well.

Comment: Save Site as Template this option is not available since we have turned on the publishing feature.

Comment: Check the edit in asnwer